# When are the adjacency matrices of non-isomorphic graphs similar?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices

From Wikipedia.

In linear algebra, two n-by-n matrices A and B are called similar if
$$    B = P^{-1} A P$$
for some invertible n-by-n matrix $P$.

If $P$ is a permutation matrix, $A$ and $B$ are **permutation similar**.

Two graphs $G,H$ are isomorphic iff their adjacency matrices 
 $A_G,A_H$ are permutation similar.

If $A_G$ and $A_H$ are not similar then $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic.

It is possible $A_G$ and $A_H$ to be similar and $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic.

Experimentally this doesn't happen often.

Recognizing matrix similarity is polynomial, $O(n^3)$.

$A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if they have the same rational canonical form (AKA Frobenius form).

> Is there characterization of the graphs for which
>   $A_G \sim A_H \implies G \cong H$?

Consider the following algorithm for graph isomorphism.

Recursively delete vertex from $G$ and from $H$ and
check the matrices for similarity. If we don't hit
bad case we will find isomorphism in polynomial time.

The exponential case is if we hit bad cases very often.

> Is there construction of non-isomorphic graphs for
>   which the above algorithm is exponential?

---

**Added**

The sequence of non-similar matrices of graphs of order $n$
starts

```
1 , 2 , 4 , 11 , 33 , 151 , 988 , 11453 , 247357
```

This coincides with [OEIS A082104 Number of distinct characteristic polynomials among all simple undirected graphs on n nodes](https://oeis.org/A082104)

If true, this would imply that symmetric matrices with $0,1$ entries
are similar iff their characteristic polynomials are equal
(which is likely known).

Comment: It should be noted that most graph isomorphism testing heuristics are mp MUCH faster than cubic, usually, so this question is not of great practical significance...

Comment: @IgorRivin the question is not of great quality. AFAICT the best _deterministic_ GI algorithms are super polynomial, maybe something like $\exp\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Yes, I am just saying that the algorithm of checking for similarity first will (in practice) greatly underperform standard heuristic. I certainly agree that the question is of theoretical interest (though is probably very hard).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no characterization known of when a graph is determined by its spectrum. The probability that a tree on $n$ is determined by its characteristic polynomial goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. It is *conjectured* that for graphs the probability goes to one.

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that the sequence is really the OEIS sequence?

Comment: @joro: which sequence?

Comment: I mean is it true that two symmetric matrices with 0,1 entries are similar iff their characteristic polynomials are equal? (For the general case wikipedia gives frobenius).

Comment: @joro: It is certainly true that real symmetric matrices are similar if and onlyif their characteristic polynomials are equal.

Answer (score 3):

There is an old result by L.Babai and D.Grigoriev saying that graph isomorphism for graphs with bounded dimension of eigenspaces can be decided in polynomial time. So yes, 
a variation of this approach - matching eigenspaces of $A_H$ and $A_G$ - is well-known.

For the second question, IMHO, the [Cai-Furer-Immerman](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=ADD70868DE07BFCCCF7E8F54C13359E7?doi=10.1.1.32.4863) graphs look like an example.